# Simple Pyramid app: using query params for routing to edit page

Tags: pyramid

I am trying to make a simple Pyramid app, and having a hell of a time figuring out what part of the syntax I'm missing. What's happening is I have an edit page for my model, and I can not figure out how to pass in the id of the entry I'm editing.

My view reads like this:

```
@view_config(route_name='action', match_param='action=edit', renderer='string')
def update(request):
    this_id = request.matchdict.get('id', -1)
    entry = Entry.by_id(this_id)
if not entry:
    return HTTPNotFound()
form = EntryUpdateForm(request.POST, entry)
if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
    form.populate_obj(entry)
    return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('blog', id=entry.id, slug=entry.slug))
return {'form': form, 'action': request.matchdict.get('action')}
```

I have created an edit template, it looks like this, and is working for the create page, which uses a different model:

```
{% extends "templates/layout.jinja2" %}
{% block body %}
<h2>Create a Journal Entry</h2>
<form action="" method="POST">
{% for field in form %}
  {% if field.errors %}
    <ul>
    {% for error in field.errors %}
        <li>{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
    <p>{{ field.label }}: {{ field }}</p>
{% endfor %}
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

And the link I have made to the template looks like:

```
<a href="{{request.route_url('action', action='edit',_query=(('id',entry.id),))}}">Edit Entry</a>
```

Which yields the url `http://0.0.0.0:6543/journal/edit?id=1`. This is new and weird to me, because I'm used to Rails, where the url would look like `http://0.0.0.0:6543/journal/1/edit` but poking around and reading the Pyramid blogr tutorial, this seems like how Pyramid likes to have routes. Unfortunately, it still gives me a 404. It seems like I am successful passing the id of the entry into a query string, but somehow I am not telling the edit page to be at that location.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: What's your route configuration? Search for config.add_route in the top-level __init__.py

Comment: I am trying to use `config.add_route('action', '/journal/{action}')` for both create and edit. In Rails, I would have separate routes, but everything I've read about Pyramid implies I should be using the same route. Thanks for giving it a look.

Comment: I can assure you `/journal/edit?id=1` is NOT how Pyramid "likes to have its routes", and pyramid_blogr sample app does not use routes like these. However, Pyramid is flexible, so you can even have /journal.php?action=edit&id=123 if you really want to :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't see where the problem is as this minimal example works, if you navigate your browser to localhost:8080/journal/edit?id=723

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pyramid.response import Response
from pyramid.view import view_config
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from waitress import serve

@view_config(route_name="root", renderer="string")
def root_view(request):
    return "root_view", request.params

@view_config(route_name='action', match_param='action=edit', renderer="string")
def action_view(request):
    return "action_view", request.params

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = Configurator()
    config.add_route('root', '')
    config.add_route('action', '/journal/{action}')
    config.scan()
    app = config.make_wsgi_app()
    serve(app)
```

Maybe you have some other problem with your routes. Can you paste them here all? Are you sure you do not have another function named update in your view?

Aside from that, you are completely free to build your routes as you wish with Pyramid.

```
config.add_route('action2', '/different/edit/{id}')
config.add_route('action3', '/someother/{id}/edit')
```

I personally would rather use one of the schemes above than the match_param predicate...